# Dummy error with \center

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I know this is a silly thing but I don't understand why does this happens. My text is not well centered but I'm using the `\center` command with all the page. This is my output:

[image: The words "Ingeniero mecatrónico" should be centered as well]

The phrase "Ingeniero mecatrónico" should be centered as well

And this is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas
\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\addbibresource{Anteproyecto.bib}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%\usepackage{nomencl}
%\makenomenclature
%%\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

\backgroundsetup{
contents={\includegraphics{escudounipamplona.png}},
angle=0, 
scale=0.45, 
color=black, 
opacity=0.1
}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de tablas}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{M{#1}}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=75pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|M{3.0cm}|X|M{2.5cm}|M{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{4}*{\includegraphics[scale=0.034]{escudounipamplona}}
    &
    \multirow{4}*{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Propuesta trabajo de grado para optar por el título de Ingeniero en Mecatrónica}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{\textbf{C\'odigo}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{1.2}\\
    &&&
    \\\cline{3-4}
    &&
    \multirow{2}*{\textbf{Pagina}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{\small\emph{Pagina \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}\hspace{15pt}}\\
    &&&\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
\BgThispage
\begin{center}
{
\Large\textbf{Realización de planes de mantenimiento basados en ingeniería de confiabilidad y propuesta de ingeniería para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta}  
\vspace{5cm}
\\
{\normalsize \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar\\

\vspace{5cm}
Programa de ingenier\'ia mecatr\'onica \\
Departamento de ingenier\'ia mec\'anica, mecatr\'onica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\newpage
\BgThispage
\begin{center}
{

\large\textbf{Realización de planes de mantenimiento basados en ingeniería de confiabilidad y propuesta de ingeniería para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta}  
\vspace{2cm}
\\
{\small \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar \\
{\small \textit{Codigo: 1116249797}} \\
{\small\textit{Correo electronico: judabo@unipamplona.edu.co}} \\
\vspace{1cm}
{\small \textit{Practica laboral para optar al titulo de}}\\
Ingeniero mecatrónico
\vspace{1cm}
{\newline\small\textit{Director}} \\
Dr. Rocco Tarantino Alvarado \\
{\small\textit{Doctorado en Ciencias Aplicadas}} \\
{\small \textit{Correo electronico: rocco.tarantino@unipamplona.edu.co}} \\
\vspace{1cm}
{\small\textit{Supervisor}} \\
Ing. Rafael Antonio Sepulveda Ayala \\
{\small \textit{Coord. de mantenimiento, Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz}} \\
{\normalsize \textit{Correo electronico: blablabla@erasmo.co}}\\
\vspace{2cm}
Programa de ingenier\'ia mecatr\'onica \\
Departamento de ingenier\'ia mec\'anica, mecatr\'onica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\newpage

\section{INTRODUCCI\'ON}
\vspace{2cm}
El Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz es el centro de salud más importante de Norte de Santander. Con categoría nivel cuarto de complejidad, su nombre es en homenaje a Erasmo Meoz Wills, primer medico oriundo del departamento quien murió el 1 de junio de 1918 y cuyos restos descansan en la entrada del edificio. La fundación del hospital data del año 1987 y concentra un volumen significativo de servicios de salud que abarcan todas las especialidades medicas. A nivel ingenieril representa un reto en lo que a su funcionamiento se refiere; consta de aproximadamente 2500 dispositivos médicos y complejas instalaciones dedicadas a servicios como el de lavandería, alimentación y mantenimiento de equipos, entre otros.
\newline\par
Un despliegue logístico de tal envergadura implica alta sensibilidad en aspectos tales como costos de mantenimiento, operación y  eficiencia energética que juntos tienen una participación significativa en la dinámica que presenta el movimiento de recursos económicos disponibles. El objetivo de esta practica empresarial es abordar desde el enfoque ingenieril propuestas encaminadas a plantear un manejo optimo de recursos a nivel energético y de costos de mantenimiento mediante una serie de actividades que abarcan dichas temáticas. Tales actividades se resumen en propuestas para la mejora de planes de mantenimiento, optimización  de la iluminación eléctrica en corredores y mejoras en equipos del área de lavandería. 

\newpage
\section{JUSTIFICACIÓN}
\vspace{2cm}
La intención de la practica empresarial consiste en  plantear una propuesta de mejora a dos aspectos claves relacionados con la reducción de costos operacionales del hospital Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta: el consumo eléctrico del hospital y la actualización de los planes de mantenimiento de  equipos entre los que encontramos calderas, secadoras y la planta de respaldo energético. Con el fin de concretar las mejoras a realizar se ha seleccionado una serie de actividades que  se basaran en estos dos aspectos, el de optimización energética y el desarrollo de actividades de mantenimiento. El fin ultimo de la practica es contribuir con el bienestar general de los usuarios del centro hospitalario y del personal en general, en particular de aquel que esta vinculado directamente con el área de mantenimiento del hospital, ademas de aportar mejoras técnicas y operacionales que contribuyan al desarrollo tecnológico de la institución.

\newpage
\section{PLANTEAMIENTO DEL PROBLEMA}
\vspace{2cm}
Un inconveniente que enfrenta el sector de la salud en Colombia esta relacionado con la carencia de recursos económicos destinados a planes de modernización y mejoramiento de la planta física de las instituciones publicas que prestan servicios sanitarios. Por lo general, una planta física moderna se traduce en un manejo energético optimo y en mejoras relacionadas con la calidad de los servicios prestados a la comunidad, por lo tanto es imperativo destinar fondos que tengan como propósito favorecer dichas condiciones. Como se menciono con anterioridad, los recursos económicos para tales proyectos son reducidos, en consecuencia no solo es necesario implementar planes de adecuación tecnológica,  también es fundamental que las propuestas realizadas sean económicas y no representen una inversión significativa para la institución puesto que en este caso siempre hay otros elementos que requieren una mayor prioridad. 
\newline\par
Las actividades propuestas como directrices de la presente practica empresarial y que se pretenden desarrollar a lo largo de la misma son inicialmente tres. En primer lugar se presenta la necesidad de mejorar el sistema de control que emplean los compresores de aire instalados en el área de lavandería; su actuación es mecánica y se espera hacer la transición a una actuación electrónica, ademas se requiere que su funcionamiento sea de tal modo que ayude a preservar la vida útil de los equipos. De igual manera, se debe plantear una estrategia de optimización energética para la iluminación eléctrica de los corredores del primer piso del hospital que implique no solo una disminución de consumo  eléctrico sino que a su vez ofrezca confort tanto a personal medico como a pacientes. Por ultimo es necesario realizar una revisión y consecuente mejora al plan de mantenimiento de una serie de equipos previamente seleccionados entre los que podemos encontrar la planta de respaldo energético, las calderas y las secadoras de la lavandería; el objetivo es modernizar dichos planes de mantenimiento y verificar que se encuentran ajustados a la normativa vigente.  

\newpage
\section{OBJETIVO GENERAL}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
Realizar planes de mantenimiento basados en ingeniería de confiabilidad y plantear una propuesta de ingeniería para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta
\end{center}

\newpage
\section{OBJETIVOS ESPECÍFICOS}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Realizar  el acopio de información, la caracterización de las actividades a realizar y la ingeniería básica de dichas actividades.
    \item Diseñar la ingeniería de detalle, sistemas de parada, puesta en marcha y preservación de los compresores del área de lavandería 
    \item Trazar un plan de optimizacion energetica para el sistema de iluminación electrica de  los pasillos y areas comunes del primer piso del Hospital Erasmo Meoz.
    \item Desarrollar planes de mantenimiento para las calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras.
\end{enumerate}

\newpage
\section{PLAN DE TRABAJO}
\vspace{2cm}
El plan de trabajo estará fundamentado en la resolución secuencial de cada uno de los objetivos específicos planteados con anterioridad. Se estima una duración total de entre 16 semanas y se espera dedicar en general un  total de 4 a 6 semanas por objetivo.
\subsection{Acopio de información, ingeniería conceptual e ingeniería básica}

En el primer objetivo se pretende realizar el acopio de información, la caracterización de las
actividades a realizar, la ingeniería conceptual y la ingeniería básica de dichas actividades.
\subsubsection{Metas}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Documentar todas las actividades a realizar
\item Realizar una descripción completa de las actividades realizando
  el levantamiento del problema 
\item Diseñar las ingenierías conceptual y  básica requeridas en todas las actividades

\end{enumerate}

\subsubsection{Indicadores}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Lista de revisión completada detallando la información recolectada.
\item Firma de minuta con el conjunto de actividades a realizar.
\item Cumplimiento de la normativa para la realización de ingeniería básica.
\item Cumplimiento de la normativa para la realización de ingeniería
  conceptual.
\end{enumerate}

\subsubsection{Actividades}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Recolectar la documentación especificada en la lista de revisión
(datasheets, planos, prospectos, etc.).
\item Hacer el levantamiento de la minuta donde se consignaran las actividades
  a realizar y que servirá como un aval por parte del Hospital Erasmo Meoz.
\item Realizar las ingenierías básica y conceptual sobre cada una de las actividades de
  la lista.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Ingeniería de detalle sistemas de arranque, parada y preservación.}
El levantamiento del problema, la recolección de información y la realización de una Ingeniería Básica son una serie de actividades que sirven de sustento para el planteamiento de la ingeniería de detalle requerida en los compresores del area de lavanderia. La Ingeniería de Detalle o Diseño de Detalle es la fase en la que quedan definidos todos y cada uno de los subsistemas, componentes o partes que integran el proyecto, de tal manera que los documentos que lo desarrollan han de ser suficientes para llevarlo a la
práctica, ya sea bajo la dirección de los mismos proyectistas o por otro equipo de
ingeniería distinto.
\subsubsection{Metas}
\begin{enumerate}
        \item Determinar el tipo de actuación y el sistema de control que se deben implementar en los compresores de lavandería.
        \item Proponer y justificar un esquema de iluminación optimo para las luces de pasillos y áreas comunes del primer piso del Hospital Erasmo Meoz.
\end{enumerate}
\subsubsection{Indicadores}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Cumplimiento de la normativa vigente para la realización de la Ingeniería de Detalle.
\end{enumerate}
\subsubsection{Actividades}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Realización de la ingeniería de detalle para los compresores de lavandería.
\item Realización de la ingeniería de detalle para la iluminación eléctrica de corredores y áreas comunes del primer piso.

\end{enumerate}
\subsection{Planes de mantenimiento para calderas, planta de respaldo energético y secadoras.}
La Ingeniería de Confiabilidad se concentra en procesos de eliminación de fallas a través del uso de diversas herramientas analíticas que permitan mejorar procesos, actividades, recursos, diseños -y otros- dentro de las tácticas de mantenimiento correctivo, preventivo y predictivo. El objetivo primordial es elevar la confiabilidad de los activos aumentando así también su disponibilidad, siempre y cuando las mejoras se fundamenten con la rentabilidad del negocio. El ultimo objetivo tiene como propósito proponer nuevos planes de mantenimiento basados en ingeniería de confiabilidad para las calderas, la planta de respaldo energético y las secadoras de lavandería. 

\subsubsection{Metas}

\subsubsection{Indicadores}
\subsubsection{Actividades}
\clearpage
\section{CRONOGRAMA DE ACTIVIDADES}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{16}
    \gantttitle{Cronograma de actividades}{16} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,16}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Objetivo 1}{1}{4} \\
    \ganttbar{Actividad 1}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Actividad 2}{3}{4}\ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7}\ganttnewline
    \ganttbar{Objetivo final}{8}{12}
    \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
    \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}
\caption{Cronograma de actividades.}\label{tab:table_label}
\end{table}

%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to have an explicit or implicit `\par` (either an actual `\par` or a blank line) between fontsize-changing commands. E.g., before the line that has `Ingeniero mecatrónico`.

Comment: Remove the `\newline` and ***always*** leave blank lines before `\vspace`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate problem is the lack of a blank line before `\vspace` and a spurious `\newline`

```
Ingeniero mecatrónico

\vspace{1cm}
{\small\textit{Director}} \\
```

will centre the text, but the font size changes and line spacing is rather weird throughout the document.